# What would be the positive and negative traits of a total matter to energy conversion drive?

Tags: science-based, spaceships, energy

Here is the basic outline for the drive:

- The drive, at its most basic, is a device that converts any matter into pure energy, and the operator can choose *exactly* what kind of energy is produced, and where it goes.
- For example, matter can be converted into kinetic energy, and applied to a ship, in the direction that the captain wants to go.  It could also be converted into electrical energy, that can then go into the ships energy grid.
- The conversion takes place in a *conversion field*, which can be either a shell on the exterior of the ship to convert interstellar dust, gas, etc. into energy, or a small field within the ship to convert the ships trash.

Excess energy can be stored for later use, in a device like the niling d-sinks of Peter F. Hamilton's *Commonwealth Saga*.

What I want to know is, would this actually be a good drive system for a spaceship?  Would this be more efficient than a matter-antimatter drive? What would happen if, say, due to a computer error, someone accidentally piloted their ship into a planet?

Comment: If you can convert matter to energy, matter IS alreay an energy storage. Why putting an inbetween step?

Comment: @L.Dutch Converting matter into energy is relatively easy, some elements _naturally_ convert themselves into energy, aka the radioactive elements.  Concentrating matter into energy, on the other hand, is _much_ harder.

Comment: I think you should split this question into two parts : First is converting matter into "energy" and second is using "energy" to do something. Both converting regular matter into "energy" and converting "energy" into kinetic force are HUGE gamebreakers.

Comment: Sorry, I meant converting _energy into matter_ on the other hand, is much harder.

Comment: @DracoAtrox, my point is that if you use matter to generate energy, you have plenty of them. Converting matter to energy has a yield, therefore it is a good design choice to keep the conversion steps to a minimum.

Comment: @L.Dutch I'mean sorry if I didn't make myself clear.   The conversion happens instantaneously, without an intermediate step.  The energy storage is for when the ship is flying through a region of space that has an extremely low matter density.  Storing the excess energy as re-condensed matter would increase the mass of the ship, which would then require more kinetic energy to accelerate at the same rate.

Comment: If you can transform matter into whatever kind of energy, lossless, you're essentially God Almighty and by definition, you are omnipotent. The drive you're proposing is, by definition, the best one it can be made unless you find an energy container denser than barionic matter.

Comment: Please define "pure energy" and "kind of energy". Energy is something you see in an equation, it's something we humans created. Something has an energy of x in a specific context if you do your math. It has a lot of implications and is really practical and so on, don't get me wrong. If there is such a thing as pure energy that I'm not aware it, I would also like to know that.

Comment: @Raditz_35 According to the principle of Mass-Energy Equivalence, objects with mass (matter) are made of condensed energy, E=mc^2 being the rule controlling the amount of energy in a given amount of mass.  "Pure" energy would be energy that has been converted from matter, but is not doing anything.  By "kind of energy" I mean what you see in equations, i.e. kinetic energy, potential energy, electrical energy, etc.

Comment: @DracoAtrox Wonderful example. E=mc². An equation that assigns an energy to an object with a resting mass. Yes, all the energy you see in the equations again. They are on paper, not in reality. E=mc² doesn't turn something into smoke, it's just an equation you see on a computer screen. There is a step missing here. I give you an example: A car is a machine that can turn fuel into energy as needed. This energy can be electrical, kinetic or heat. We have your spaceship on earth, congratulations. You skipped over the most important part

Comment: PS: I know what you mean btw. You want a perfect spaceship. But please consider: a) There is no "pure" energy, so point 1 doesn't make sense. b) You have not told us where the flaws might be. All you have done is define a perfect spaceship. Find a flaw in something that is perfect? Well it is perfect because you skipped over all the important parts. If I describe a car as I did above, a car is the perfect machine for transportation. We need to know more, how you achieve your energy-mass conversion, what that pure energy might be and how you transform that energy ...

Comment: @Raditz_35, one of the important factors to make this site work is "accept the premise of the question" maybe this drive isn't possible, dragons aren't possible and we don't complain about them (much), accept the premise of the drive and work from there.

Comment: @Separatrix I'm not saying it isn't possible, I'm saying it doesn't make any sense / isn't a full premise. To pick up your dragon example, the question is equivalent to asking: "Imagine there would be something that defeats everyone in battle, what is the weakness?" He might be talking about dragons, but we do not know that because nothing has been specified. It could be a ghost for all we know. And that isn't even 10% of the problem I have with the current question because no variables from some random equations suddenly have a physical manifestation. Maybe it is a ghost drive

Comment: @Raditz_35, we had a batch of "unstoppable" questions, though they've tailed off recently, treat it as a black box, you only need to know how it reacts externally.

Comment: @Separatrix Oh and PS: I don't mind it for a story at all. "I have the perfect space drive. But I invented a weakness for a situation in my story". Perfectly fine. But I don't think it is valid in the current form to ask such a question without being more specific about what this drive might be and where weaknesses could lie. As I stated first, the weaknesses are completely arbitrary at this point. Luckily I still think this applys to your 2nd comment to further explain why I think we need more information. Currently, the answers come down to: If you hit something, there still is a crash ...

Comment: @Raditz_35 I know in its current state it's a perfect drive... and that's _boring_!  I'm looking for people to poke holes, and possibly think up hypothetical disaster scenarios.  Right now, the only disaster scenarios I have are accidentally piloting the ship through a habitable planet, thus ruining it, or "uncontrolled conversion", where the matter is converted into hard radiation and heat energy, instead of anything useful.

Comment: @DracoAtrox You can do that arbitrarily. I mean that in all honesty. You could imagine your drive needs an opneing where someone could shoot a rocket into and the death star explodes. Just one example. It is somewhat difficult to do with a pure description of how any drive works in principle other than that no pure energy exists

Comment: When converting into kinetic energy, what do you do to the impulse?

Comment: @Raditz_35 So this drive also transfers damage it suffers to the Death Star? Man, that thing just can't catch a break...

Comment: Doesn't converting matter directly into kinetic energy in this way violate the law of conservation of mass? If I consume 1 Kg of mass to accelerate my ship in one direction, then consume 2 Kg of mass to accelerate myself back towards my initial starting point, then consume another 1 Kg of mass to decelerate myself back to my initial velocity... what happened to the 4 Kg of mass I just consumed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A perfect black box drive system, non-reaction unfuelled drive system. Efficiency is irrelevant, you're not putting any fuel in so it has no running cost. You've saved yourself from having to work out how to transport large quantities of dangerous fuel/antimatter. In practical terms it can't even be compared to any drive system we've considered.

Ignore the people who shout "it'll never work" just because it'd never work. That's a minor detail.

If you need to accelerate you just fly into something, plenty of reaction mass to get you started on your journey. The home system asteroid belts would be stripped within a decade. Political campaign groups would start up to protect the moons of the outer worlds. Unscrupulous haulage companies would demolish mountains for reaction mass.

The effect of flying a ship full pelt into a planet does depend on how good your external field is. The field would also be running as your navigation shield, absorbing and converting any mass that would otherwise damage your ship into fuel for your ship, but what happens when you get too much mass? Vent it as heat, no problem. If you hit a planet, you're just going to leave a cylindrical hole through the planet and a lot of heat. Kill a few people, cause some interesting geological phenomena, strange weather patterns, nothing terribly exciting for the people on board.

What's potentially more interesting is what happens when you hit another ship.

Answer (score 5):

If you can convert matter into kinetic energy directly, you have the perfect drive. It is reactionless and lossless. Any conventional drive, say a drive using the radiation produced by annihilation, must needs be less efficient.

What would happen if a ship with such a drive crashed into a planet? Space is mostly empty, so your ship would need a pretty large conversion field, possibly larger than the planet itself. A sizeable part of the planet, or even the entire planet would be instantly converted to whatever "kind of energy" had been selected. Your ship might be vaporized, or accelerated to near-lightspeed, gaining the mass of a planet in the process.

But since such a device most likely contains a large amount of handwavium, other arbitrary effects may occur.

Comment: @L.Dutch It answers the question "would this actually be a good drive system for a spaceship".

Comment: then please flesh it out a bit.

Comment: @L.Dutch there is nothing to flesh more. the result of the collision depends on settings of the device in the moment of the collision and nature of the device. The device will break and nothing will happen or it might suck the planet into blackhole - without knowing the nature device there is nothing to say about, and OP is free to make fantasies about that himself.

Comment: @MolbOrg, he fleshed out more already. My request to was addressed to the first version

Comment: @L.Dutch My apologies. I didn't check that. Definitely, the initial version was too short.